# Wix installer -Title on the welcome screen truncated on Win2012R2

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I am seeing a strange behavior where the title of a particular msi package is truncated on Win 2012 R2 but the same is displayed completely on a Win 7 and Win 2008 R2 system.

The msi package in question uses the inbuilt Wix UI Minimal dialog set.

Is there a reason why we see such a difference in the behavior of the displayed text on the dialogs?

I built another sample msi package and this package exhibits the same behavior as well. So i am beginning to think that this is something related to the Wix UI dialog set.

I am using Wix v3.10. Kindly advise.

Win 2012 R2(Observe the truncation on the title bar):

[image]

Win 7 SP1(There is not truncation):
[image]

Comment: Try adding a screen shot of this to allow people some context. Most likely it has to do with the theme used in Your Windows 2012 R2 installation. You can try to use a different theme to check.

Comment: Kindy review the updated question with screenshots.

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul: Do you have any ideas on what could be wrong here? I tried changing the Font size for the default font in the TextStyle table. However, that does not help. Anything else that you want me to try? I dont want to go through the pain of importing the dialog source and editing the attirbutes. Any help would be very much appreciated.